# Troubles using realloc function

Tags: c

I have a trouble with my code and I need your advice, when I compile the code it displays a warning at the realloc line, it says: "Assignment makes pointer from integer without cast", but it compiles and everything runs nice until I need to expand my array, when I enter how many numbers more I need it crashes. Do you have any idea what is causing this? How can I fix it? 
Thank you.

Edit: Already fixed it! the following code is now functional.
Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct numer{
    int limit;
    int start;
    double *num;
    double avg;
};

void fill(struct numer *data);
double ave(struct numer data);
double vari(struct numer data);

int main (){
    int n,op;
    printf ("!!++***Programa para calcular desviacion estandar, la media y la varianza***++!!");
    printf("\nIngrese el número de datos que desea introducir: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    struct numer data;
    data.start=0;
    data.num = malloc(n*sizeof(*data.num));

    while(1){
        data.limit=n;
        fill(&data);
        data.avg=ave(data);
        printf("\nLa media es igual a %lf", data.avg);
        printf("\nLa desviacion estandar es igual a %lf", sqrt(vari(data)));
        printf("\nLa varianza es igual a %lf",vari(data));
        printf("\nDeseas añadir mas datos?, presiona 1 para aceptar, 2 para salir: ");
        scanf ("%d",&op);
            if (op==1){
                printf("\nCuantos datos mas deseas añadir?: ");
                scanf("%d",&op);
                n+=op;
                data.num = realloc(data.num, n*sizeof(*data.num));
            }
            else return 0;

    }

}

void fill(struct numer *data){
    for (;data->start<data->limit;data->start++){
        printf("\nIngresa el dato %d: ",data->start+1);
        scanf("%lf",&data->num[data->start]);
    }
}
double ave(struct numer data){
    double ave=0;
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<data.limit;i++){
        ave+=data.num[i];
    }
    ave/=data.limit;
    return ave;
}
double vari(struct numer data){
    double semi=0;
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<data.limit; i++){
        semi+=pow((data.num[i]-data.avg),2);
    }
    semi/=data.limit;
    return semi;
}
```

Comment: Please show some good faith and share what you have tried so far. It would also help to reduce your problem, e.g. by getting rid of all the standard deviations. You should *always* check the result from `realloc`

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I reduced the code to the part it was failing and I noticed my dumb mistake, a missing ampersand.

Comment: well, that compiler message you posted as part of the question is one (of many) reasons that warnings should be fixed, not ignored. (as you just found out for your self).

Comment: per the posted answer, you should have seen several other warning messages from the compiler besides the one you posted.  When the compiler told you about the implicit declaration of those function, then you should be reading the man page for those functions to find what was wrong with your code.  I.E. the missing #include statement.

Comment: in general, write code for humans to read, the compiler doesn't care.  That means meaningful variable names, #defines for 'magic' numbers,  appropriate vertical spacing, appropriate horizontal spacing, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't included `stdlib.h` where the prototypes for `malloc` and `realloc` are located.

Without its prototype, the compiler assumes `realloc` returns `int` instead of `void*`, and you assign that `int` to `data.num`, a pointer. When you assign an integer to a variable declared as a pointer, you get the warning.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't notice it, it solved the warning and then I noticed a missing ampersand.